# Updating Table Cell Accessory when Split View Controller Collapses/Expands

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

In apps like the Settings app, when the `UISplitViewContoller` is collapsed, the `UITableView` cells display the standard '>' disclosure accessory icons:

[image: Settings app in portrait orientation]

On devices like the Plus-sized iPhones when rotating to landscape and the full `UISplitViewController` becomes visible, the disclosure icons disappear:

[image: Settings app in landscape]

When configuring the cells initially, it's possible to simply call `self.splitViewController.isCollapsed` to find out what the current state of the split view controller is. However when a transition occurs after that point, I'm not sure what the best way to receive notifications of that occurrence.

The easiest solution I've considered is to just call `self.tableView.reloadData()` inside the view controller's `viewWillTransitionToSize` method, but that seems like a really 'brute-force' way of doing it.

Has anyone done this sort of implementation? How did you solve it?

Comment: Haven't used it myself, but it sounds like a job for a [UISplitViewControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisplitviewcontrollerdelegate).

Comment: Ideally yes, but I've got a parent view controller where I'm already using the `delegate` (To manage state of all of the currently visible view controllers). I was hoping there would be another way to receive transition notifications on just the current view controller's level. I was just looking at the `- (void)collapseSecondaryViewController:(UIViewController *)secondaryViewController forSplitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController` method on `UIViewController`, but that doesn't seem to get called at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! I discovered how to do it! The Apple [iOS 8 sample code on size classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AdaptivePhotos/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014636) demonstrates how to do it.

I was setting up my `UITableViewCell` instances only in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` data source method, which of course, only gets called once for each cell's creation.

Apple's sample code configures the table cell accessory view in the `willDisplayCell` delegate method, and <s>this method appears to be called on each visible cell automatically when a `UISplitViewController` transition occurs. :)</s>

**Edit:** Okay, on further exploration, it turns out it's not automatic. It's an `NSNotification`.

Here's the code from the Apple Sample app. In the view controller's `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ListTableViewController.showDetailTargetDidChange(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIViewControllerShowDetailTargetDidChange, object: nil)
}
```

And the method the notification triggers:

```
func showDetailTargetDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    /*
        Whenever the target for showDetailViewController: changes, update all
        of our cells (to ensure they have the right accessory type).
    */
    for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
            tableView(tableView, willDisplay: cell, forRowAt: indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```